# How to Solve 404 error on frontend?

Tags: magento2, php, sql, php-7, luma-theme

Getting 404 error on frontend page backend Admin panel is perfectly working frontend page only through error what is the reason behind that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 404 error typically indicates that the requested webpage or resource could not be found on the server. In the context you provided, where the backend admin panel is working fine but the frontend page is displaying a 404 error, there could be several possible reasons for this issue. Here are a few common ones:

Incorrect URL or routing: Double-check the URL or route being used to access the frontend page. Ensure that it is correct and matches the expected route defined in your application's routing configuration.

Missing or misconfigured files: Check if all the necessary frontend files, such as HTML, CSS, JavaScript, or any other assets, are present in the expected directories on the server. Verify that the file names, extensions, and paths are correct.

Permissions and access restrictions: Ensure that the frontend files and directories have appropriate read and execute permissions for the web server to access them. Additionally, check for any access restrictions or authentication mechanisms that might prevent access to the frontend page.

Server configuration issues: Examine the server configuration to ensure it is correctly set up to serve the frontend files. Verify that the server is configured to handle the requested URL or route and that it is pointing to the correct document root or directory.

Caching issues: If you recently made changes to the frontend page or its files, it's possible that the browser or a caching mechanism is serving an older version of the page. Try clearing your browser cache or using a private browsing window to eliminate caching as a potential cause.

Backend API issues: If the frontend page relies on data or resources from the backend API, make sure that the API endpoints are functioning correctly. If the API endpoints have changed or are not responding as expected, it could result in a 404 error on the frontend.

To troubleshoot the issue further, you can examine the server logs, debug the frontend code, and perform network inspections using browser developer tools. These steps should help you identify the specific cause of the 404 error and guide you toward a resolution.

bin/magento cache:status
bin/magento cache:enable
bin/magento cache:disable
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:upgrade
follow this commands